# what does the sign of $ \ s_{\alpha} (20, \frac{\pi}{3} ) \ $ mean?

Tags: calculus

A ball is thrown from the ground level with initial speed $ \ v \ (m/sec) \ $ and at an angle of $ \ \alpha \ $  with the horizontal . It hits the ground at a distance  $ \ s(v,\alpha)=\frac{v^2 \sin (2 \alpha)}{g} \ $ where $ \ g=9.8 \ m/s^2 \ $

(a) what does the sign of $ \ s_{\alpha} (20, \frac{\pi}{3} ) \ $  mean ?

**Answer:**

Since $ \ \ s(v,\alpha)=\frac{v^2 \sin (2 \alpha)}{g} \ $ , we get

$ s_{\alpha}(v,\alpha)= \frac{2 v^2 \cos (2 \alpha)}{g} \\ \Rightarrow s_{\alpha} (20, \frac{\pi}{3} )=\frac{2(20)^2 \cos (\frac{2 \pi}{3})}{9.8}=-40.81 $

Thus the sign is negative.

But what does  $ \ S_{\alpha}(v,\alpha) \ $  mean ?

Comment: It appears you're taking a partial derivative, so something is decreasing.

Comment: here $ \ s \ $ denotes the position and I think $ \ s_{\alpha} \ $ can be described as change of position with respect to $ \alpha \ $

Comment: Is my calculation  above is correct ? what is $ \ \cos (\frac{2 \pi}{3}) \ =?  $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that if the initial angle is increased to more than $\pi/3,$ the distance the ball will travel before hitting the ground will decrease.  More precisely, it means that in some interval about $\pi/3,$ the distance traveled is a decreasing function of the initial angle.